# Is there a SQL mode for MySQL allowing "WHERE x = NULL" (meaning "WHERE x IS NULL")?

Tags: mysql

I know that using `column = NULL` in an SQL statement´s WHERE clause results in an empty result set.

As this is very inefficient in programming environments, I´m searching for a way to let MySQL interpret `column = NULL` like `column IS NULL`, maybe by setting an SQL mode?

Comment: "inefficient" but **correct**.

Comment: You can use [`<=>`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to) instead. I wouldn't though. This is not portable.

Comment: Unclear what you are asking

Comment: @ling.s - Doesn't seem unclear to me, they are asking for a MySQL equivalent of [`SET ANSI_NULLS OFF`.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188048.aspx)

Comment: It's not inefficient. It's just a matter of understanding the language.

Comment: You can create a function and manage the NULL inside it

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?

Answer (score 0):

Well, at least PostgreSQL does have a parameter for that

```
transform_null_equals = true
```

When is set to **true**, the query parser will transform

```
field = NULL
```

to

```
field is NULL
```

beforehand. Something tells me there's an equivalent parameter hidden in MySQL less documented params.

**EDIT as of 2020-07-15**

My "not really a solution" might be one of my first answers at SO. I'm somewhat ashamed for answering something about another DBRMS engine instead of what I was asked by the OP.

Anyway, the correct answer would be using the `<=>` operator as others have said in their answers already. You replace  `=` for that and it will behave as other comparisons:

```
 A = B  // zero if different, one if equals, this is treated as a boolean result
 A != NULL // always null, therefore not false nor true.  
 A <=> B // zero if different, one if equals, zero is one of the variables are null, 1 if both are.
```

This is not a setting and therefore it's behavior would never be session-wise or DDBB wise.

Comment: Is this a postgres setting @ffflabs ? We would love to set it so it's just true always.  Developers keep writing field = x forgetting the null case so when null is passed, well, we get screwed.

Answer (score 0):

> You can use [`<=>`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to) instead. I wouldn't though. This is not portable.

(Thanks to Martin Smith who [pointed me to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20611614/is-there-a-sql-mode-for-mysql-allowing-where-x-null-meaning-where-x-is-nul/21702254#comment30844128_20611614) this which was a solution to my problem)

Answer (score 0):

You can have a case statement in your WHERE clause to use the correct syntax:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-conditional.html

```
SELECT * FROM my_items WHERE 
    CASE WHEN 1=1 THEN mac = '08:00:2b:01:02:03'
         WHEN 1=2 THEN mac IS NULL
    END;
```

Obviously, the first case (WHEN 1=1) will always be called in this example.  You can put your own logic in that satisfies your condition.